# Using "Button" from Toolbox in Vector Panel Designer, for a CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canalyzer

I am writing testcases in CAPL and want to activate each test case by using "Button" from Panel Designer. 
The problem is that whenever I pressed the Button, it reacted as if it were pressed twice.

I just simply add a code like this to make that problem visible.
(The system variable of "@sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1" is linked to the Button in the Panel Editor)

```
on sysvar sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1  
{
    putValueToControl("Window","CAPL Output View",@sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1);
}
```

I expect to see only --> `Value of @sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1 =1`

### But the output is like this:

Value of @sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1 =1
Value of @sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1 =0

Answer (score 1):

on sysvar X{...} event procedure reacts to **value change** of X.So in case of button press (0->1) value will be set to one then on button release (1->0) value will be set to zero, so you change the value of X twice. This is why you are getting trigger twice.

To react only once on such button press event, and get notification only once, please use the keyword **this**  and condition statement.

```
on sysvar sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1  
{
    if (this==1) /* Following block is called only once, on button press 0->1 */
    {
     putValueToControl("Window","CAPL Output View",@sysvar::Test_Cases::TC1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. It is correct, with this code you can prevent it. But the same thing happens not only to buttons also switches and I saw some videos on youtube, when they make the same usage, the switch stays stable. I do not know, maybe there is something wrong in my testing environment.

Comment: In case if you are using switch control, make sure that property 'Button Behavior' = False, then the switch shall stay stable. Then the value will not flicker from between 0 and 1 and 0 again on every click.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response, this issue became hot for me nowadays. As you suggested, when I set Button Behavior' to False, this time there is no response from the Switch. It became like inactive element in the panel...

Comment: Element is inactive because you haven't attached any variable .Make sure that your sysvar is attached to button.Check access options of your sysvar,(read/write only) and "Event on Value Assignment" in System Variables configuration.

Comment: Hey YesIO, I actually solved the problem, yes you are right, button behaivor should be set to False, but it is not enough. Also Mouse Activation Type should be set to "Left", I do not know why.. I could not find a satisfactory answer...